# Exclude Google Analytics page tracking

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics

My friend works at a small hosting company and needs help with getting more specific Google Analytics results.

When the hosting company disables non-payed hosting account visitor sees that page with a link with an explanation and visits it. Visits are visible in GA but how to ignore them?

How to setup to exclude visits and page views from a referral of disabled hosting account.

Comment: I think you would need to do this at a code level, or at least that is _one_ of the ways you could do it. For example, in PHP if you get the referral page (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) then you can just put an `if` statement around the `_trackPageview` to prevent it from firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration option in Google Analytics to ignore referrers.

If you're using the older [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) library see the [_addIgnoredRef()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiSearchEngines#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addIgnoredRef) method.

If you're using the new [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) library then it is configured in the Web Interface in the Admin section. See [Referral exclusions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830).